# Integrating elfinder with s3 in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, amazon-s3, file-manager, elfinder

I am trying to integrate elfinder in Laravel 4.2 using `barryvdh/laravel-elfinder` package. This works perfectly for the local file system. I need to integrate it with AWS S3. For that I have used flysystem driver. In this packages config file, I have defined root like this

```
'roots' => [
        [
            'driver' => 'Flysystem',
            'adapter' => new \League\Flysystem\AwsS3v2\AwsS3Adapter( \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
                'key'    => 'key',
                'secret' => 'secret',
                'region' => 'us-east-1',
            )), 'bucket_name', '')
        ]
    ],
```

But this doesnt seem to work. I get this error `{"error":["errConf","errNoVolumes"]}`

Have anyone successfully done this before. Please help me.